# Как увеличить толщину линий в svg?

Tags: android, svg

У меня есть картинка в `svg` формате:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportWidth="593.727"
    android:viewportHeight="593.727">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M491.362,593.727H102.374c-20.865,0 -37.84,-16.975 -37.84,-37.84v-448.5h464.668v448.5C529.202,576.752 512.228,593.727 491.362,593.727zM79.677,122.529v433.357c0,12.516 10.182,22.697 22.697,22.697h388.989c12.516,0 22.697,-10.182 22.697,-22.697V122.529H79.677z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M550.8,91.913H42.927V58.382c0,-20.86 16.973,-37.831 37.835,-37.831h192.852C276.618,8.58 286.12,0 297.506,0c11.399,0 20.907,8.578 23.905,20.551H512.97c20.859,0 37.83,16.971 37.83,37.831V91.913L550.8,91.913zM58.07,76.77h477.587V58.382c0,-12.51 -10.178,-22.688 -22.688,-22.688h-205.57l-0.148,-7.42c-0.145,-7.24 -4.516,-13.131 -9.745,-13.131c-5.219,0 -9.586,5.893 -9.736,13.136l-0.154,7.415H80.762c-12.512,0 -22.692,10.177 -22.692,22.688V76.77z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M144.621,546.275c-15.949,0 -28.924,-12.977 -28.924,-28.926V196.011c0,-15.95 12.975,-28.926 28.924,-28.926c15.95,0 28.926,12.976 28.926,28.926V517.35C173.547,533.299 160.571,546.275 144.621,546.275zM144.621,182.228c-7.599,0 -13.781,6.183 -13.781,13.783V517.35c0,7.6 6.183,13.783 13.781,13.783c7.601,0 13.783,-6.184 13.783,-13.783V196.011C158.404,188.411 152.222,182.228 144.621,182.228z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M243.094,546.275c-15.95,0 -28.925,-12.977 -28.925,-28.926V196.011c0,-15.95 12.976,-28.926 28.925,-28.926c15.949,0 28.925,12.976 28.925,28.926V517.35C272.019,533.299 259.043,546.275 243.094,546.275zM243.094,182.228c-7.6,0 -13.782,6.183 -13.782,13.783V517.35c0,7.6 6.183,13.783 13.782,13.783s13.782,-6.184 13.782,-13.783V196.011C256.876,188.411 250.694,182.228 243.094,182.228z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M341.565,546.275c-15.949,0 -28.926,-12.977 -28.926,-28.926V196.011c0,-15.95 12.977,-28.926 28.926,-28.926s28.926,12.976 28.926,28.926V517.35C370.491,533.299 357.515,546.275 341.565,546.275zM341.565,182.228c-7.6,0 -13.783,6.183 -13.783,13.783V517.35c0,7.6 6.184,13.783 13.783,13.783s13.783,-6.184 13.783,-13.783V196.011C355.347,188.411 349.165,182.228 341.565,182.228z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M440.038,546.275c-15.955,0 -28.934,-12.977 -28.934,-28.926V196.011c0,-15.95 12.979,-28.926 28.934,-28.926c15.949,0 28.924,12.976 28.924,28.926V517.35C468.962,533.299 455.987,546.275 440.038,546.275zM440.038,182.228c-7.605,0 -13.791,6.183 -13.791,13.783V517.35c0,7.6 6.186,13.783 13.791,13.783c7.6,0 13.781,-6.184 13.781,-13.783V196.011C453.819,188.411 447.638,182.228 440.038,182.228z" />
</vector>
```

Как можно увеличить толщину линий,  что нужно добавить для регулировки толщины  линий?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно в нужный `path` добавить

```
android:strokeWidth="20" //например 20
android:strokeColor="#FFF"
```